# Numpy: automatically load files in .npz to new variables depending on key

Tags: python, numpy

I am given a .npz file (data.npz) which contains 3 .npy files. I explicitly know one of the three files has the key 't'. I do not explicitly know the keys of the other two files. (I know I can call list() on this file to see the keys, but I don't want to do this manually, it should be automated).

I want to extract all three files, and assign them to variables. key 't' should be assigned to t, while the other two "unknown" keys should be assigned to variables a, b (regardless of their actual keys). Idealistically, t solution should work regardless of how many additional keys exist besides 't', and should assign them to variables alphanumerically rather than by their key name (excluding t).

So far, I've tried two solutions:

the first converts the .npz file to a dictionary

```py
data = dict(np.load('data.npz'))
t = data.pop('t')
a = data.pop((list(data)[0]))
b = data.pop((list(data)[0]))
```

but the problem with this solution is that I can't iterate over whatever number of files are present, and each variable has to be explicitly defined

the second uses a for loop:

```py
data = np.load('data.npz')
for var in data:
    globals()[var] = data[var]
```

this is much smoother, except that I can't figure out how to exchange the key name (excluding t) to "a, b, c" etc in sequence.

Sorry if this is confusing... I'm pretty confused!

Comment: Creating a variable number of variables names `a`,`b`,`c`... in sequence is not good Python style.  Not only is it hard to create them, it's also a pain to pass them around (in and out of functions), and to otherwise use them.  Use a Python dictionary or list to collect these arrays.

Comment: Yea that's what I've done in my first solution, less the issue of explicitly defining each variable from the dict keys. I understand the "style" point but this question is in regards to a specific use case so the mobility of the variables isn't a real concern for me here. Just asking for a solution that combines the benefits of both methods I've mentioned above, or makes them more efficient, etc.

Comment: The only time consuming step is loading the array, the `data[key]`.  Assigning that array to a variable, list or dictionary value doesn't take much time.  I'd just elaborate on the `for var` loop, assigning the `data[var]` array to what ever variable you want.  It doesn't have to be pretty, since you aren't doing something pretty/pythonic.